# Android refresh LinearLayout after click

Tags: android, button, refresh, android-linearlayout

How can I refresh the LinearLayout called "contNoticias" after doing a click in a button?

Here is my code:

```
contNoticias = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contNoticias);

    int arrayNoticias = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayNoticias; i++) {
        //agregar views
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(antro.this);
        relativeLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        relativeLayout.setId(+1);
        contNoticias.addView(relativeLayout);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textviews_menu);

        //Separar variables
        try {
            httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();
            String response = handler.post(url + "MyDayFiles/muro.php");
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int u = 0; u < array.length(); u++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(u);

                tituloN += jsonObject.getString("nombre") + "/";
                tituloN = tituloN.replace("null", "");
                titulosN = tituloN.split("/");

                noticiaN += jsonObject.getString("noticia") + "/";
                noticiaN = noticiaN.replace("null", "");
                noticiasN = noticiaN.split("/");

                imagenN += jsonObject.getString("foto") + "/";
                imagenN = imagenN.replace("null", "");
                imagenesN = imagenN.split("/");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //imagen
        ImageView imagenNoticia = new ImageView(antro.this);
        imagenNoticia.setId(+2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imagenNoticiaParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250);
        imagenNoticiaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        imagenNoticiaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        imagenNoticiaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
        imagenNoticia.setLayoutParams(imagenNoticiaParams);
        imagenNoticia.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        Picasso.with(this).load(url + "MyDayFiles/imgnoticias/" + imagenesN[i]).into(imagenNoticia);
        //imagen

        //titulo
        TextView tituloNoticia = new TextView(antro.this);
        tituloNoticia.setId(+3);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tituloNoticiaParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tituloNoticiaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imagenNoticia.getId());
        tituloNoticia.setLayoutParams(tituloNoticiaParams);
        tituloNoticia.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        tituloNoticia.setTextSize(12);
        tituloNoticia.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        tituloNoticia.setText(titulosN[i]);
        //titulo

        //noticia
        TextView textoNoticia = new TextView(antro.this);
        textoNoticia.setId(+4);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textoNoticiaParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textoNoticiaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tituloNoticia.getId());
        textoNoticiaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imagenNoticia.getId());
        textoNoticia.setLayoutParams(textoNoticiaParams);
        textoNoticia.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        textoNoticia.setTextSize(12);
        textoNoticia.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        textoNoticia.setText(noticiasN[i]);
        //noticia

        //agregar views
        relativeLayout.addView(imagenNoticia);
        relativeLayout.addView(tituloNoticia);
        relativeLayout.addView(textoNoticia);

    }
```

The thing is I want to refresh the views inside my LinearLayout when the user clicks a button "Post" so the new post can be displayed at the screen at the moment the user clicks the button

Comment: put the try block inside a method and call it every time you want to retrieve the data and refresh the data. \n

Use SwipeRefreshLayout instead

Comment: @GeetChoubey can you show me how to add the try method to refresh it?

Comment: `SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout; `
`refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        refreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);`


`@Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        //Remove all views
        //Add views back
    }`

Comment: I read the entire code properly, you will need to add the entire snippet inside a method say `private void refreshMyViews(){...}' and call it inside the onRefresh() method

Comment: maybe you have to call invalidate() on the linear Layout

Comment: @NoFuchsGiven I already tried with invalidate but it doesnt work

Comment: hi dude, did you find a solution ?